# Use credentials to make API calls from a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

What is a secure way to use credentials to make REST API calls from a Jenkinsfile?

For example, the following would not be secure because the username and password are exposed in code:

```
sh "curl -D- -u username:password -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://<ip-of-server-with-rest-api>/path/to/api/endpoint"
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/#withcredentials-bind-credentials-to-variables)

Here is an example:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'amazon', 
 usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
 // available as an env variable, but will be masked if you try to print it 
  out any which way
 // note: single quotes prevent Groovy interpolation; expansion is by 
  Bourne Shell, which is what you want
  sh 'echo $PASSWORD'
 // also available as a Groovy variable
  echo USERNAME
 // or inside double quotes for string interpolation
  echo "username is $USERNAME"

 sh "curl -D- -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://<ip-of-server-with-rest-api>/path/to/api/endpoint"
}
```

Your credentials will be hidden in Console Output.

Comment: FYI, answers that only link to external sources do not receive as many upvotes as do answers that paraphrase the contents of the links in the stack overflow answer in addition to providing links for further reference.  This is because links change over time, and people read these stack overflow questions and answers many years after they are posted.  I am taking the time to write this because it seems that you just joined the site.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I'll try to do best.